# Why is not my url a fully qualified url for paypal?

Tags: url, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I have this code

```
<?php

require '..\..\vendor\autoload.php';

define('SITE_URL','https://www.historietas.mx');

$paypal = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
        new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
            'my_redential',
            'my_secret'
        )
);
?>
```

And this code

```
    $redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
    $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(SITE_URL.'\controladores\pagos\pay.php?success=true')
        ->setCancelUrl(SITE_URL.'\controladores\pagos\pay.php?success=false');
    $payment = new Payment();
    $payment->setIntent('sale')
        ->setPayer($payer)
        ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
        ->setTransactions([$transaction]);

    try{
        $payment->create($paypal);
    }
    catch(PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $e){
        echo $e->getCode();
        echo $e->getData();
        die($e);
    }
    echo $approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();
```

and I have this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'ReturnUrl is not a fully qualified URL'
```

I don't know what's hapenning I am not using any special character in the url, why is giving me this error? please help, it is very frustating...

Comment: Are backslashes legal in an URL? I'm pretty sure RFC3986 says no.

Comment: URLs cannot contain backslashes. Use forward slashes.

Comment: Whoa! that was the problem, the backslashes... thank you David and EJP, this was making me nuts, thank you very much...

Answer (score -2):

remove space from url from your Url that's the issue

```
include 'vendor/autoload.php';
$checkUrl = 'https://yourdomein.org/user/registration/paypaypal-ch?approval=true&plan=single&email=dghdg@dfgsdh.com&firstname=dshdh0d&lastname=dhdas';
 try {
      \PayPal\Validation\UrlValidator::validate($checkUrl);
       echo "Validated\n";
     } catch (InvalidArgumentException $ex) {
       echo $ex->getMessage() . "\n";
    }
```

Comment: OP did not have spaces in URL

Answer (score -2):

```
Remove ?success=true
```

and

```
   Remove ?success=false
```

from

```
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(SITE_URL.'\controladores\pagos\pay.php?success=true')
        ->setCancelUrl(SITE_URL.'\controladores\pagos\pay.php?success=false');
```

and it will wotk for sure.

Comment: This is not the issue.  It's the backslashes as said in the comments.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem and it was resolved by using

```php
route('your route name '['parameter 1','parameter2'])
```

```php
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(route('your route name '['parameter 1','parameter2']));
```

Comment: This is not the issue.  It's the backslashes as said in the comments.  Also, your code has syntax errors.